# Issue with clearing canvas when drawing graphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Ok, essentially what im trying to do is datadisplay for my website with Chart.js

now this behavior is in chrome, I'm not really focusing on ie9 atm, as that has its own range of issues and won't event display the grapths.

The problem is this, the first draw works fine. however the website's nature means that people might navigate away from it (and the entire website is a series of div's that are hidden or faded in depending on which buttons are clicked) and then come back to view the grapth again.

Despite my best efforts, the grapths keep getting drawn on the canvas over and over again the effect is extremely annoying as it means they are overlayed onto each other in constantly bigger fashion like Matryoshka doll that show up depending on where on the grapth your mouse is. Generally its a mess.

Now whats throwing me is i've tried what appear to be the 'big' two ways to redraw the canvas in a number of ways to no avail. None of these methods seem capable of actually destroying the old grapth before the new one is drawn.

Relevant code:

```
//GRAPTH FUNCTIONS.
function firstgDraw(){

//get canva 
var canvas1 = $('#g1').get(0);
var canvas2 = $('#g2').get(0);
var canvas3 = $('#g3').get(0);
var canvas4 = $('#g4').get(0);

//get canvas context
var canv1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
var canv2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
var canv3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");
var canv4 = canvas4.getContext("2d");

//hacky method
canvas1.width = canvas1.width;
canvas2.width = canvas2.width;
canvas3.width = canvas3.width;
canvas4.width = canvas4.width;

//clear canvas by clearing the rectangle.  
canv1.clearRect(0,0,canvas1.width,canvas1.height);
canv2.clearRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);
canv3.clearRect(0,0,canvas3.width,canvas3.height);
canv4.clearRect(0,0,canvas4.width,canvas4.height);

.....
var chart1 = new Chart(canv1).Line(data1,options);
var chart2 = new Chart(canv2).Line(data2,options);
var chart3 = new Chart(canv3).Line(data3,options);
var chart4 = new Chart(canv4).Line(data4,options);
```

Note im not using te hacky and clear rect method at the same time, i'm interchanging them, the behavior is exactly the same.

I've also tried doing this every time the 'back' button is pressed. by placing the above code in their like so

```
 $('#backtoMain').click(function(){     
        $('#DataDis').hide();
    //get canva 
    var canvas1 = $('#g1').get(0);
    var canvas2 = $('#g2').get(0);
    var canvas3 = $('#g3').get(0);
    var canvas4 = $('#g4').get(0);

    //get canvas context
    var canv1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
    var canv2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
    var canv3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");
    var canv4 = canvas4.getContext("2d");

    //hacky method
    canvas1.width = canvas1.width;
    canvas2.width = canvas2.width;
    canvas3.width = canvas3.width;
    canvas4.width = canvas4.width;

    //clear canvas by clearing the rectangle.  
    canv1.clearRect(0,0,canvas1.width,canvas1.height);
    canv2.clearRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);
    canv3.clearRect(0,0,canvas3.width,canvas3.height);
    canv4.clearRect(0,0,canvas4.width,canvas4.height);

        $("#dataField").fadeIn();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Are you saying clearRect() doesn't clear the canvas?

Comment: Well given the Matryoshka doll effect of every previous grapth remaining and having a new one drawn over it ever time you enter that section of the page. I'm pretty certain its not working.

Comment: Could you restate your question--and maybe add a fiddle?  It might just be me but I have no idea what you're asking :-/

Comment: both methods should definitely clear the canvas, so the problem is somewhere else in your code. can you post full example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion, i've manged to fix it now with a alternative method. Neither of these standard canvas clearing methods were working ~ god knows why. I've manged to avoid the problem with an if check to see if the grapth needs redrawing, and if it does im just destroying the datasets on existing grapths as opposed to drawing entirely new objects.

A werid one solved by a hacky work around, thanks for trying guys. I would not recommend chart.js.